# Unable to get Div width by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML Div with several sub Divs. When I'm trying to get the main Div's width, it is **getting a wrong width different from the width that showing in the inspect element**. What I exactly want is the visible width which is the width that showing when inspecting the element. I tried with `outerWidth()` and `offsetWidth` but didn't work. `offsetWidth` gave me "Undefined". How can I get this?

```js
var x = $(".main").width();

$("button").on("click", function() {
 alert(x + " (Inspect element has width 571)");
});
```

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">One</div>
  <div class="sub">Two</div>
  <div class="sub">Three</div>
  <div class="sub">Four</div>
</div>
<button>
GET MAIN DIV WIDTH
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do OffsetWidth or offsetWidth?

Comment: @Chris offsetWidth

Comment: Seems to get the correct width to me. For  example: I inspect the `.main` element, it has `514px` and the alert also shows `514px`. Of course if you use `alert(x + " (Inspect element has width 571)");` you will get different results, lol, cause `571` is just a string added by you, from your example at least that can be deduced.

Comment: Also, if you resize the browser window somehow, of course it will get the `x` wrong. You have to put `var x = $(".main").width();` inside the click event.

Comment: @Ionut I updated with a picture. I need that red marked width and alert says something else

Comment: Refresh the page with the inspect element open and see what happens. As I said in my last comment, I'm almost certain that is happening in your case. So you should modify according to that comment.

Comment: I got it. As you said, var x need to be inside the click event. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch out, when you get the width of the div. If it is before the **page loads** or before you **resize the window**, your solution won't work.

When i get the width in the click event i always get the right one.
You could also just do it once after the page loaded with:

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

in same as:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  // your code
});
```

```js
var x = 0;

//alternativ
$(function() {
  //this will only happen once and won't react to resize
  x = $(".main").width();
  console.log("div width: " + x);
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  // resizing is no problem
  x = $(".main").width();
 alert("div width: " + x);
});
```

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">One</div>
  <div class="sub">Two</div>
  <div class="sub">Three</div>
  <div class="sub">Four</div>
</div>
<button>
GET MAIN DIV WIDTH
</button>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `inline Flex`

```js
var x = $(".main").width();

$("button").on("click", function() {
 alert(x);
});
```

```css
.main{
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">One</div>
  <div class="sub">Two</div>
  <div class="sub">Three</div>
  <div class="sub">Four</div>
</div>
<button>
GET MAIN DIV WIDTH
</button>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the OP output and yours?

Comment: @Ionut the differeence seems to be that it's the width of the elements inside instead of the screen (doesn't resolve the OPs problem though)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. He wanted to get the correct width of the `.main` element and he wasn't getting it correctly because the element width was being resized after page load because probably he was opening the Inspect element or something, thus the incorrect variable `x` declaration. Anyway, the OP confirmed my suspicions in his comment.